# copy cell data from one sheet to another based on condtion

Tags: excel, function

want to copy data from one sheet to another for following
column A         column B
College ID  College name
1   Andaman & Nicobar Islands Institute of Medical Sciences
2   Viswabharathi Medical College
3   S V Medical College
4   SVIMS - Sri Padmavathi Medical College for Women
5   Santhiram Medical College
6   RVS Institute of Medical Sciences
7   Rangaraya Medical College
8   Rajiv Gandhi Institute of Medical Sciences
9   Rajiv Gandhi Institute of Medical Sciences
10  Rajiv Gandhi Institute of Medical Sciences
11  P E S Institute Of Medical Sciences and Research
12  NRI Medical College
13  NRI Institute of Medical Sciences
14  Nimra Institute of Medical Sciences
15  Narayana Medical College
16  Maharajah Institute of Medical Sciences
17  Kurnool Medical College
18  Konaseema Institute of Medical Sciences & Research Foundation
19  Katuri Medical College
20  Guntur Medical College
21  GSL Medical College
22  Great Eastern Medical School and Hospital
23  Government Siddhartha Medical College
24  Government Medical College
25  GITAM Institute of Medical Sciences and Research
26  Gayathri Vidya Parishad Institute of Health Care & Medical Technology
27  Fathima Instt. of Medical Sciences
28  Dr. P.S.I. Medical College 
29  Ayaan Institute of Medical Sciences
30  Apollo Institute of Medical Sciences and Research
31  Andhra Medical College
32  Alluri Sitaram Raju Academy of Medical Sciences
33  ACSR Government Medical College
and so on

and so on

in 2nd sheet  i have college list like this

Column B
college Name
Alluri Sitaram Raju Academy of Medical Sciences
Andhra Medical College
Dr. P.S.I. Medical College 
Government Siddhartha Medical College
Great Eastern Medical School and Hospital
GSL Medical College
Guntur Medical College
Konaseema Institute of Medical Sciences & Research Foundation
Kurnool Medical College
Narayana Medical College
NRI Medical College
P E S Institute Of Medical Sciences and Research
Rajiv Gandhi Institute of Medical Sciences
Rajiv Gandhi Institute of Medical Sciences
Rangaraya Medical College
Santhiram Medical College
S V Medical College
and so on(college list will be same from 1st sheet but in another order)

now i want to copy same college id from 1st sheet where college name match in 2nd sheet(in another sheet)

requirment is as follows(example)

college ID  College Name

32          Alluri Sitaram Raju Academy of Medical Sciences
31          Andhra Medical College
28          Dr. P.S.I. Medical College
23          Government Siddhartha Medical College
22    Great Eastern Medical School and Hospital

i am setting up a new web application, and need to do as per above because 1st sheet list is master list, and in second sheet is based on available courses
if fucnction didnt work as per my requirement.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Unfortunately it is very difficult to understand the layout of your sheet how you have described in your question. It might be worth adding screen prints of your sheets for clarity and a screen print of how you want the resulting sheet to look. Also, have a read of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: While posting questions, kindly try to use a good formatting, so that it will be easier for others to answer it and also if someone is stuck on the same problem may search for it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula - `=INDEX(Sheet1!A:B, MATCH(B2,Sheet1!B:B, 0), 1)`